# Zoom in Zoom out problems in CSS

Tags: css, html

Hi here i am pasting code of my page in that i had one background image. In that i need to put buttons. When i am doing zoom in and zoom out buttons are moving from position.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {   
            background:SteelBlue url('BG_BLUE_NEW.jpg') no-repeat center center;
        }
        .login
        {
            margin-top:300px;
            height:300px
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="login">
        <form style="padding-left:370px;margin-bottom:0px;">
            <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
            <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
            <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
            <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
            <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at thsi:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {   
            background:SteelBlue url('BG_BLUE_NEW.jpg') no-repeat center center;
        }
        .login
        {
            width:100px; /*<- important edit*/
            margin: 0 auto; /*<- important edit*/
            margin-top:300px;
            height:300px
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="login">
        <form style="margin-bottom:0px;"><!-- removed padding -->
            <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
            <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
            <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
            <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
            <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What's going on here:

I set a specified with (100px) on the `.login` div to hold the inputs which also have a 100px width.

Then I applied `margin:0 auto` which reads: set the margin above and below to 0, left and right to 'auto' (grow-to-fill)

after that I removed the padding-left on the `<form>` element

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RN5EV/)

Comment: Hey actually i want buttons at 370px from left side these are coming at center. How to resolve this.